# Distributed training with Keras on Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, distributed

Can anybody help me to find a simple but complete example of a distributed training script running under Tensorflow/Keras? I need the script to contain a simple Keras model that read the input data from a dataset. The implementation strategy is to be data parallelism, i.e. multiple parallel workers reading different batches of data and sharing a common set of model parameters stored on a parameter server.
I searched the internet for many days but everything I found was incomplete and the descriptions/instructions was not sufficient to build my own code out of the pieces I found.

Comment: Hey Shahriar! Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42409884/keras-tensorflow-prediction-on-multiple-gpus?rq=1

Comment: Hi, I need distributed training. The link you mentioned is for distributed prediction after you have a model trained.